# C# json DeserializeObject inheritance

Tags: c#, json

I have a Parent class and a Child class, the json string is containing properties of Child class but when I do a DeserializeObject I can't get those properties because Child became a Parent.

For example :

```
class Data {
    public List<Parent> Parents;
}

class Parent {
    public string Foo;
}

class Child : Parent {
    public string Bar;
}

var data = new Data { Parents = new List<Parent> { new Child{Bar = "a"} } };
Console.WriteLine(data.Parents.Count); // <= it prints 1
Console.WriteLine(data.Parents.OfType<Child>().Count()); // <= it prints 1

var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(dataJson);

Console.WriteLine(data.Parents.Count); // <= it prints 1
Console.WriteLine(data.Parents.OfType<Child>().Count()); // <= it prints 0 instead of 1
```

What can I do about that ? Newtonsoft.Json can manage to do what I want ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JsonSerializerSettings' TypeNameHandling`

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(dataJson, settings);
```